# Boot Virtual Box off SD Card

Tags: linux, boot, ssh, virtualbox, sd-card

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3B running Raspbian Stretch Lite. I want to enable SSH but I don't have a USB keyboard. So some Googling revealed that if I place a file named `ssh` at the root of the card, SSH would be automatically enabled. But this doesn't seem to be the case. So what I would like to do is boot a virtual machine. I have the OS installed on an SD Card which is working perfectly fine, but I can't seem insert it into Virtual Box to treat it as a boot device. What do I need to do so that I can run Raspbian atop it?

PS: I'm on Windows.

Thanks

Comment: You could always use a PC-compatible Linux distribution inside VirtualBox to modify the Pi’s filesystem.

Comment: The boot directory in the pi is fat32 - I actually wonder if the problem is elsewhere. Firewalls? IP addresses?

Comment: I figured since it's Linux, it must be compatible, but I guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really do what you're trying to do for multiple reasons.

Virtualbox only supports x86 and the raspberry pi is a ARM based machine. Virtualbox also, as far as I recall wouldn't boot off a SD card, and the way the raspberry pi boots (which is seriously unusual) is different from a x86 booting off bios, or various UEFI flavours used on X86 and even higher end machines that run arm or power.

In theory you *might* be able to boot the raspberry pi image on an appropriately set up QEMU install - but that's something I've not gotten working myself.

Comment: That's disheartening, but makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the question, I understand that the actual goal is to ssh into the Pi headless.

> I want to enable SSH but I don't have a USB keyboard. So some Googling revealed that if I place a file named ssh at the root of the card, SSH would be automatically enabled.

I confirm it is the correct method. I have done it on Raspberry Pi 2B. All you need is to be able to mount the SD Card on another machine.  I did it on Mac, which is probably the worst case (no support for ext).

For the Raspberry Pi 3B+, I lost patience and I configured the ssh with keyboard, mouse TV and HDMI cable.

Please confirm.

Comment: As I now have the appropriate equipment to create Raspbian images, I have not followed this up and am currently unable to as my raspberry pi is under constant heavy usage. I will let you know next chance I get to experiment with this. Thanks anyway.